# Boostrap 4 Grid System on mobile and desktop

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to build a grid system using boostrap 4, I have a newspaper that on tablet/desktop mode show three columns each row, instead on mobile mode I would like to show only one column each row.
The documentation to this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/
describe the Class prefix across multiple devices.
On tablet/desktop mode everything run well, but on mobile mode I have problems.

**This picture show how should be on mobile mode**

[image]

**This pics show the problems that I have on mobile mode**

[image]

**This is the code:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <!-- Article 1 -->     
       <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
         <div class="content">
            <div id='column1' class="column">
            Lorem ipsum etc...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Article 2 -->
       <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <div class="content">
            <div id='column2' class="column">
            Lorem ipsum etc...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Article 3 -->
       <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <div class="content">
            <div id='column3' class="column">
            Lorem ipsum etc...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `col-12 col-md-4` is all you need - this is assuming none of the child classes affect the width of the content, which I suspect they do looking at your image

Comment: In Fiddle, that actually seems to work OK.  It must be what @Darren Sweeney says.  Maybe your content, collumn classes or the id's have some CSS that is affecting the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `class="col-4"` it's enough

You don't need all these styles `col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
 integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <!-- Article 1 -->     
       <div class="col-4">
         <div class="content">
            <div id='column1' class="column">
            Lorem ipsum etc...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Article 2 -->
       <div class="col-4">
        <div class="content">
            <div id='column2' class="column">
            Lorem ipsum etc...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Article 3 -->
       <div class="col-4">
        <div class="content">
            <div id='column3' class="column">
            Lorem ipsum etc...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I solved ! Thanks for your help (@Darren Sweeney ) ! The problem was on class="content", there was the property display: inline-block; I deleted it, and now run correctly on all browers. I used this <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4` is unnecessary. Bootstrap grid work well. Maybe your title (SERIE BI) is too long. Try to give it `max-width: 100%`